# quantum state homodyne tomography

Tags: quantum-optics, density-operator, wigner-transform

I'm confused as to whether quantum state homodyne tomography can be successfully performed for detector efficiency less than 1/2, in the limit of infinite number of trials.  My understanding is that the detected marginal distributions would be Gaussian convolutions of the distributions obtained with perfect efficiency.  If we assume that the system has been fully and accurately characterised I would have thought that deterministic deconvolution could then be performed to obtain the perfect marginal distributions.  From these the Wigner function could then be found (by inverse Radon transform).  I emphasise that this is in the ideal limit of infinite repetitions and no other noise sources.

However, in the literature I find several references to unbounded density matrix elements if an inequality for the detector efficiency is not satisfied (see, for example, http://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.52.R1801).  If my initial assumption is correct that the perfect deconvoluted marginals could be extracted via the infinite trials then these marginals could then be converted to the density matrix via the Wigner function and any matrix element taken.

The only thing I can think of is that they are trying to measure the density matrix directly without having to perform the deconvolution, and are thus using the convoluted marginals to calculate the Wigner function and density matrix.  Perhaps on the grounds that this would be a more satisfying detection of non-classical states, given that there could never be certainty as to whether they had correctly characterised their system.

Perhaps a summary of my question would be: in the limit of infinite trials and a completely characterised Gaussian noise process (ie detector inefficiency) why cannot the equivalent perfect efficiency marginal distributions be found via deterministic deconvolution?

Thanks!